# Show UI with "Press ENTER to NextScene()" after boss fight

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on the kind of Space Invaders type of game where after a boss fight I want to enable UI Text "You Won, Press Enter to just to another scene".

So I have my Boss1 Game Object where I have `Boss.cs`. I store there a bool isBossAlive which I initialize as true and switch to false when the boss dies.

I also have UI.Text in which I have a script that will move the player to the next scene if he/she press enter. I have it under Canvas. I initialize them as Inactive as I don't want to see the text when I'm going through the level + I don't want to have a possibility to skin level anytime. I want to use "ENTER" only after I kill the boss.

Finally, I have a third game object that I called "Game Session" and a `GameSession.cs` attached to it.

What I'm trying to achieve is to access bool isBossAlive in the GameSession.cs so once the boss is killed (and `isBossAlive` will switch to false) I could use that as a trigger to use `IsActive(true)` from there to my `UI.Text` game object.

Comment: Please [edit] to include the actual code, ideally as a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You can use Singleton pattern. In your `Boss.cs` in the beginning you can write

```
public static Boss instance
public void Awake(){
instance=this;
}

.......

//Check Boss From GameSession.cs
public void CheckBoss(){
return isBossAlive;
}
```

In your Game Session you can access `CheckBoss` function like that:

```
if(!Boss.instance.CheckBoss){
//Boss is dead now
//You can activae UI Text and ınput control (For Enter Key)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a few design suggestions, hope it helps:

- I think the usual name for your `GameSession` class/object is `GameController`;
- When you `Start()` your `Boss`, store a reference to the `GameController`
- When your `Boss` dies, make  it call a `gameController.onBossDied()` callback method;
- Create a `UIController` script attached to your `Canvas` object, to control everything related to UI elements (enabling and disabling `UI.Text`s, for example);
- Store a reference to `UIController` on `GameController` and the other way around;
- On `GameController.onBossDied()` call `uiController.showEndText()`;
- Read the `Enter` input on `UIController`, to keep the contexts concise
- When detecting an `Enter`, call `gameController.onEnter()`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just do

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Enter)
{
     if(Boss.IsBossAlive == false)
     {
          SceneManager.LoadScene("NextScene")
     }
}
```